# When adding an integer only the first number is recorded

Tags: c

I am working on a project and when I try to add a multi digit number to a stack of integers only the first digit is recorded I am pretty sure the problem is with the way I am reading them in here but I don't understand what is causing this to happen. If you could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

```
int main(int argc,const char *argv[])
{
  FILE *src = input_from_args(argc, argv);

    if (src == NULL)
    {
        printf("%s", "Invalid Source");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
    {
    struct stack * equation = NULL;
    equation = (struct stack*)malloc(sizeof(struct stack));
    equation -> top = -1;

    int i;
    int c;
    while( argv[i] != NULL)
    {
      c = *argv[i];
      i++;
      push(equation,c);
    }

    if(strcmp(argv[1],"-e") == 0)
    {
      evaluate(equation);
      printf("%i \n", pop(equation));
    }
    else if(strcmp(argv[1],"-c") == 0)
    {
      convert(equation);
    }
    else if(strcmp(argv[1],"-g") == 0)
    {
      other(equation);
    }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

struct stack
{
   int arr[100];
   int top;
};

void push(struct stack *st, int c)
{
   if (st->top == 99)
   {
      printf("Stack is full");
      return ;
   }
   st->top++;
   st->arr[st->top] = c;
}
```

Comment: This line `while( argv[i] != NULL)` is using an uninitialised `i`.

Comment: This does not compile.  Can you provide what is necessary for a compilable example?

Comment: `c = *argv[i];` do you enable and take note of all compiler warnings? That would have revealed my previously commented bug too.

Comment: Yes I do, it did not give a warning for that although I did notice it and initialized it to see if that was the problem a while ago and it made no difference in performance so I left it as it was.

Comment: Why do you need the body of the code under an `else` when you already did `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);`?

Comment: You really must initialise `i`. If it made "no difference" that's no excuse for skipping the rules. Do you have **all compiler warnings enabled**? It's quite usual for a compiler to warn about using an ininitialised variable.

Comment: Note: Rather than the cumbersome `equation = (struct stack*)malloc(sizeof(struct stack));`, use `equation = malloc(sizeof *equation);`.  Easy to write, and maintain.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that it is your *only* problem, but I am seeing:

```
    int i;
    int c;
    while( argv[i] != NULL) // i is uninitialized
    {
      c = *argv[i]; // c is an integer, *argv[i], if valid, is a character
      i++;
      push(equation,c);
    }
```

So, I am not certain what you are after there, but I don't think you are approaching it correctly.

Look into `sscanf` or `atoi`. For instance,

```
sscanf ( argv[i], "%d", &c );
```

or

```
c = atoi ( argv[i] );
```

might be what you're looking for.